Samba cant connect, exept
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have set up a new samba server as my old server is getting ancient :D
I only use linux when setting up a new server these days, so it can be years between every time.
But I can't connect to the shares unless I open the file browser on the windows machine as administrator.
I have tried every trick I could find out there, but nothing has worked.
smb.cfg from testparm
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = Samba Server
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[Movies]
        comment = Filmer
        path = /media/sda1/Movies
        read only = No
        valid users = adm operator "username"


[Serier]
        comment = Serier
        path = /media/sdb1/Serier
        read only = No
        valid users = adm operator "username"


Resolved:
I randomly entered my windows machine network settings and set "My computer is part of a company network" and again set the workgroup to "WORKGROUP".
I don't know why this had to be done in this case, as I still have full access to my old samba server without this step. But that's for another day....
If anyone know how this could be solved with the samba config plz let me know.
This is a file server used in my home for sharing to my HTPC and backup.
The problem was that I could enter the server but could not open the shares without opening the file browser as administrator on the Windows pc.
